# Profiling datastore queries in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app for GAE which uses datastore extensivly. I would like to see which queries happen most frequently. But the built-in statistics shows me only total reads/writes without specific details. Is there a way to see the detailed info on that or may be there is some profiling open-source project of a kind?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know which queries occur most frequently? The usualy reason to do this in an RDBMS is to build indexes for those that are slow, but App Engine requires indexes for queries anyway - they're generally not optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appstats, for [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html).

Answer (score 4):

[Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html) can give you detailed information about all of the App Engine RPCs (datastore, memcache, etc) that are made in a given HTTP request.

There are also several open-source "mini profilers" for GAE that allow you to display the profiling information (both Appstats and normal method call profiling) easily on the rendered page itself:

- https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler - For Python
- https://github.com/jriecken/gae-java-mini-profiler - For Java